# Vue.js: Set checkboxes checked if statement is true

Tags: checkbox, model, vue.js, vuejs2

I had the following checkbox in my old handlebar view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type='checkbox' name='xmlOnline[]' value="stepstone" class='' {{#if (ifIn 'stepstone' job.xmlOnline)}} checked="checked" {{/if}}> Stepstone
    <input type='checkbox' name='xmlOnline[]' value="karriere" class='' {{#if (ifIn 'karriere' job.xmlOnline)}} checked="checked" {{/if}}> Karriere
</div>
```

So if job.xmlOnline has "stepstone" as value, it should mark it as checked. Same goes for "karriere".

Now I am trying to achieve the same thing in Vue.js for my POST form.
This is how the object "job" looks like: http://t2w-api.herokuapp.com/jobs/590c20d42b1c4300046bb1b9

So it can contain either "karriere", "stepstone", both or "null".

What I got so far in my component:

```
<div v-for="(xml, index) in job.xmlOnline">
    <input type="checkbox" :checked="xml == 'stepstone'"> Stepstone {{ index }}
    <input type="checkbox" :checked="xml == 'karriere'"> Karriere {{ index }}
</div>
```

Checkboxes get checked, but I have them duplicated. I also do not know how to add a v-model.

This is the source of my component. Did something similiar with "qualifications"/"responsibility": https://github.com/markusdanek/t2w-vue/blob/mdanek/2-auth-system/src/components/backend/JobEdit.vue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A possible solution

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       :checked="job.xmlOnline && job.xmlOnline.includes('stepstone')"
       @change="onChange('stepstone', $event)"> Stepstone
<input type="checkbox" 
       :checked="job.xmlOnline && job.xmlOnline.includes('karriere')"
       @change="onChange('karriere', $event)"> Karriere
```

And the onChange method

```
methods:{
  onChange(value, $event){
    if (!this.job.xmlOnline)
      this.job.xmlOnline = []

    const index = this.job.xmlOnline.findIndex(v => v == value) 
    const checked = $event.target.checked

    if (checked && index < 0)
      this.job.xmlOnline.push(value)
    if (!checked && index >= 0)
      this.job.xmlOnline.splice(index, 1)
  }
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MmXXxp?editors=1010).

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly :)

Can you help me how I would post this checkbox when I add a new job?
https://jsfiddle.net/ush3mps5/

Comment: I also forgot, that it is also possible, that job.xmlOnline can also contain nothing. :/

Comment: @mrks When you say nothing do you mean it's null, or that it's an empty array. If it's an empty array, it will still work as in the answer. As far as how would you post it, that depends on your server side.

Comment: Sorry to be not clear enough. I meant that it can be also "null" like in this example: 57c52e875028100300236b6b

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! :-)
Any last recommendations on my first comment (how to use v-model) when posting a new "job"?

Comment: @mrks The question is do you want to post them as individual values or as an array? There are so many ways you could do it. If you want individual values, you could parse them out of your array and add them to whatever request you are making to submit. Without knowing how you want to submit, it's difficult to answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144272/discussion-between-mrks-and-bert-evans).

Comment: I want to post them as the xmlOnline array. So when none of both checkboxes is checked, job.xmlOnline will be "null". If the checkbox for stepstone is checked, xmlOnline will have the value "stepstone" and vice versa for karriere. @bert-evans

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" :value="party.status" 
@change="updateStatus"
 :checked="party.status == 1 ? true: false"
 id="status" name="status"/>
```

and in component method

```
updateStatus(e){
            if(e.target.checked){
                store.commit('updateStatus', 1);
            } else {
                store.commit('updateStatus', 0);
            }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just bind it to a literal as

```
:true-value="1"
```

and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
<b-form-checkbox class="col-sm-1 small" :value="1" switch v-model="user.nameb" :state="Boolean(user.nameb)" name="checkbox-validation">
    <b-form-invalid-feedback v-show="!Boolean(user.nameb)" :state="Boolean(user.nameb)">Not Verified</b-form-invalid-feedback>
    <b-form-valid-feedback v-show="Boolean(user.nameb)" :state="Boolean(user.nameb)">Verified</b-form-valid-feedback>
</b-form-checkbox>
```