# Pre-selection option in vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

Usually in bootstrap I do it like this. All targets in array " this.targets", and selected in array "selected_targets"

```
   <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="tags[]" value="{{$tag}}"
                       @if(in_array($tag,$anketTarget)) checked="1" @endif >
```

But how to use pre-election in Vue?

```
 <div v-for="target in targets">
    <input type="checkbox" id="target" v-model="checkedTarget" checked> {{target.name}}
    <input type="checkbox" id="target" v-model="checkedTarget">{{target.name}}
                                 </div>


<script>
    export default {
   data() {
            return {
                targets: "",
                selected_targets: [],
                checkedTarget: []
            }
        },
</scrpt>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43983149/7897328) for checking if the checkbox should be checked or not.

This [documentation page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox) can help you for retrieving checked checkboxes.